# Drupal: What is wrong with my base_path to my libraries folder

Tags: drupal-6, recaptcha

I get the following error: 
**Warning: require_once(/libraries/recaptchalib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in eval() (line 3 of /home3/quikappd/public_html/rulpon/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).**

In drupal 6 I am attempting to add captcha to an old content type that has a php html form built into it.  I add the captchalib file to the library folder in my drupal instance, but I keep getting the error message noted above.  I have tried **dirname**, **base_path** and various other urls to get to the folder.  What am I do wrong?

This is what I had for base_path `-> require_once(base_path().'libraries/recaptchalib.php');`
then this for dirname `-> require_once ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/libraries/recaptchalib.php');`
then just straight url `-> //require_once('decon.com/sites/all/libraries/recaptchalib.php')`;

Answer (score 0):

According to [`base_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/6) doc, it returns an URL segment. For example, if the drupal site homepage is on `http://www.example.com/foobar`, it would return `/foobar`

That's why it doesn't help in locating an include file with php.

When knowing where the file is relative to document root, you may use:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/site/all/libraries/recaptchalib.php");
```

Or if the file is part of a module, a better method is be to locate it through:

```
drupal_get_path('module', 'name-of-module')
```